# GROUP BY affecting WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query where I want to see claims where there is no service type associated with any of the lines. My query below is returning the one line where it meets the criteria. However, there is another line with a service type which means I don't want to see this. Because of the group by my query is seeing line and returning it and then looking at line two separately and removing it

```
select distinct a.claim_id,
       count(a.receipt_id) as Count_Receipts, 
       sum(a.billed_amount) as Total_Billed_Amount,
       (case 
         when a.service_type_id is null then 
             count(a.receipt_id) 
         else 0 
       end) test
from cd_roc_claim_item a, 
     cd_hospital b , 
     cd_Claim_header c
where a.hospital_id = b.hospital_id
and a.claim_id=c.claim_id (+)
and b.hos_cat_id='PUBL'
and c.claim_status is null
and a.claim_id='123456'
group by a.claim_id, 
         a.service_type_id 
having count(a.receipt_id) =1
       and sum(a.billed_amount) in 
         ('80','160','240','320','400','480','560','640','720','800')
;
```

Comment: This is a horrible example of SQL syntax.  Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Provide some kind of schema and sample data if possible.

Comment: This is what is used in our team unfortunately. I can't provide data due to privacy reasons

Comment: We don't need to see the real data, of course, just make it up, like hospital_id ='XXX'. For the tables, we need only the columns that are used in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to report the claims where there are no values for `service_type` in any claim item:

```
select ci.claim_id
     , count(ci.receipt_id) as count_receipts
     , sum(ci.billed_amount) as total_billed_amount
     , count(*) as claim_items
from   cd_roc_claim_item ci
       left join cd_hospital ho
            on  ho.hospital_id = ci.hospital_id
       left join cd_claim_header cl
            on  cl.claim_id = ci.claim_id
where  cl.claim_status is null
group by ci.claim_id
    -- , ci.service_type_id  -- Edit (following comments): this was part of the problem
having count(ci.service_type_id) = 0
and sum(ci.billed_amount) in (80, 160, 240, 320, 400, 480, 560, 640, 720, 800);

CLAIM_ID   COUNT_RECEIPTS TOTAL_BILLED_AMOUNT CLAIM_ITEMS
---------- -------------- ------------------- -----------
1                       2                 160           2
```

The problem is the hospital category, because every claim item could be for a different hospital with a different category. Do you want to see only claims where all items are for hospital category `PUBL`, or where there is at least one, or what?

Test setup:

```
create table cd_hospital
( hospital_id integer primary key
, hos_cat_id varchar2(10) );

create table cd_claim_header
( claim_id varchar2(10) primary key
, claim_status varchar2(10) );

create table cd_roc_claim_item
( claim_item_id integer generated always as identity primary key
, claim_id references cd_claim_header not null
, hospital_id references cd_hospital not null
, billed_amount number not null
, service_type_id integer
, receipt_id integer );

insert into cd_hospital (hospital_id, hos_cat_id) values (1, 'PUBL');
insert into cd_hospital (hospital_id, hos_cat_id) values (2, 'PRIV');

insert into cd_claim_header(claim_id, claim_status) values (1, null);
insert into cd_claim_header(claim_id, claim_status) values (2, 'CLOSED');

insert into cd_roc_claim_item (claim_id, hospital_id, billed_amount, service_type_id, receipt_id)
select ch.claim_id, ho.hospital_id, 80, null, 1
from   cd_claim_header ch
       cross join cd_hospital ho
where  ch.claim_id = 1
union all
select ch.claim_id, ho.hospital_id, 640, 123, 1
from   cd_claim_header ch
       cross join cd_hospital ho
where  ch.claim_id = 2;
```

**Edit in response to comments:**

To include a case where a claim has items with and without a service type, we'll update one row:

```
update cd_roc_claim_item set service_type_id = null
where  claim_id = 2 and hospital_id = 1;
```

Now the test data looks like this:

```
select ci.claim_id, ch.claim_status, ci.hospital_id, ho.hos_cat_id, ci.service_type_id, ci.receipt_id
from   cd_roc_claim_item ci
       join cd_claim_header ch
            on  ch.claim_id = ci.claim_id
       join cd_hospital ho
            on  ho.hospital_id = ci.hospital_id
order by ch.claim_id;

CLAIM_ID   CLAIM_STATUS  HOSPITAL_ID HOS_CAT_ID  SERVICE_TYPE_ID  RECEIPT_ID
---------- ------------ ------------ ---------- ---------------- -----------
1                                  2 PRIV                                  1
1                                  1 PUBL                                  1
2          CLOSED                  2 PRIV                    123           1
2          CLOSED                  1 PUBL                                  1
```

As I understand it, you want to report claim 1 (aggregated to one row) because none of its items have a service type. Claim 2 should not be shown, because one of its items has a service type.

Comment: Thanks William, So the claim that I was discussing is still being returned when I use this code. It still seems to be doing the same thing of identifying the first line and selecting it and then identifying the second and ignoring it. As there is more then one line it should be ignored completely. (Hope this makes sense)

Comment: Is my test as shown above giving the wrong results, in which case where exactly? Or is it going wrong when you extend it to your actual database (which I can't see)?

Comment: So in your results I would say it looks correct, however when I run the select query on my database it is still bringing back the incorrect ones

Comment: OK, then extend my test case to reproduce the issue you are having and we'll talk ;)

Comment: So I have updated your claim 2. This is similar to what is being returned. I should not be seeing this claim at all, but I am seeing the bottom line.

Comment: Using the updated test data, my query still only shows claim 1. Could the issue be the hospital category? (Though that wouldn't add a row. Something is different anyway.)

Comment: If the category was changed to Publ on the first line would it still be returned? Your code won't actually run on my machine so can't test myself. I removed all of the hospital elements from my original query but I am still getting that incorrect claim back.

Comment: I took the hospital category out because I didn't know the requirement for reporting it, and I wanted to simplify the test case as much as possible. If my test case won't build for you, my guess would be you have an older version of Oracle that doesn't support identity columns, in which case change it or remove it. You'll need to include an actual working test case in your question otherwise we will get nowhere.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't understand what you want me to do with your code. I have it working like above. However, I am unable to correct it as it's the same as my original question?

Comment: My test case appears to give the correct results, but you are saying the slightly different version you are working with does not. I don't know what's different, so you need to edit your question to include a working test case similar to mine that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: So I finally managed to get it. I removed the group by service type id in your query.